# Trigger.io Facebook.Authorize

Tags: facebook, trigger.io

I'm attempting Facebook Single Sign On with Trigger.IO and when testing with the IOS simulator the following happens:

1. Facebook Dialogue Opens
2. User Logs In
3. User Authorizes App
4. User clicks Okay to return to the native app.

At step 4 the following Safari notification is displayed and the app is never reloaded:

```
"Cannot Open Page"
"Safari Cannot Open the Page because the address is invalid"
```

As far as I can tell my APP ID is correct as the process would never make it to step 4 otherwise. My Facebook app is set up with the following details:

```
Native iOS App
SSO enabled.
```

No idea what I'm missing here but any help would be greatly appreciated! I've found answers to similar issues with native apps where the Facebook APP ID should be prepended with "fb", in the plist. But nothing related to trigger.IO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression in v1.4.10 that we fixed in v1.4.11 - if you've got:

```
"platform_version": "v1.4",
```

In your application configuration, you'll pick up the fix automatically.